# Hive type casting error from Int to varchar

Tags: casting, hive, ioexception

I have a partition `TABLEA` with column datatype `INT`.
Created a `TABLEB` with column datatype `Varchar`.
Pushed the data into `TABLEB` from `TABLEA`.

`select * from TABLEB` with limit is working.

`select * from TABLEB` failing giving below error.

```
select count(columnname) from TABLEB failing :

Error: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.BytesColumnVector cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.LongColumnVector
```

Comment: Examples of data and DDL statements you used to create those tables would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: @VolodymyrGlushak  DDL:  CREATE TABLEB(
COL1 VARCHAR(10))
PARTITIONED BY (
start_date date)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
STORED AS orc;

Answer (score 1):

When you are pushing data into TABLEB use type casting for the column.
Ex:

```
insert into TABLEB
select
cast(columnname as string) as columnname
from TABLEA
```

Comment: first the select should work  insertion come after that.